# Can I set an element's size to fit its potential content, rather than its actual content?

Tags: css, width

Consider this bar of buttons:

```css
body {text-align: right;}
```

```html
<button>Save</button>
<button>Cancel</button>
<button>Delete</button>
```

Now let's say that the last button's content changes:

```css
body {text-align: right;}
```

```html
<button>Save</button>
<button>Cancel</button>
<button>Click me again to confirm deletion</button>
```

As you can see, this change in the rightmost button triggered all buttons to its left to move.

To avoid this, I'd like the button's original size to fit the larger one of its two possible contents.

Of course, I can try to "achieve" this in many ways. The simplest and ugliest is to experiment how much width the larger content requires and "hardcode" it:

```css
body {text-align: right;}

#del {display: inline-block; width: 220px;}
```

```html
<button>Save</button>
<button>Cancel</button>
<button id="del">Delete</button>
```

However, I consider it a non-solution because it cannot be guaranteed that this width will be the same for everyone else. If someone has a weird font, or uses text magnification, or views the site on mobile, or whatever, then I suppose setting the button's width to a hardcoded value could produce weird results.

Another way, I suppose, would be to (a) Initially put the longer text to the button (b) Get the button's width through JavaScript and save it (c) Put the actual, shorter text to the button and set its width to that value. To my intuition, however, this looks like a horrible hack and overkill.

What is the canonical solution to troubles like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider data attribute to add both texts using pseudo elements then control the opacity to hide/show them:

```css
div {
  text-align: right;
}

#del {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative
}

#del:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:1px; /*there is 1px default padding */
  text-align:center;
}

#del:after {
  content: attr(data-alt);
  opacity:0;
}


#del:hover::before {
   opacity:0;
}
#del:hover::after {
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div><button>Save</button><button>Cancel</button><button data-text="Delete" data-alt="Click me again to confirm deletion" id="del"></button></div>
```

You simply need to know which one will be the wider one to keep it in-flow to define the width and make the other one `position:absolute`.

You can also keep the main text inside:

```css
div {
  text-align: right;
  font-size:14px;
}

#del {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#del span {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:1px; /*there is 1px default padding */
  text-align:center;
}

#del:after {
  content: attr(data-alt);
  opacity:0;
}


#del:hover span {
   opacity:0;
}
#del:hover::after {
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div><button>Save</button><button>Cancel</button><button  data-alt="Click me again to confirm deletion" id="del"><span>Delete</span></button></div>
```

Comment: Very nice. Doesn't this, however, break accessibility?

Comment: @gaazkam I don't think so since it's about a *delete* button but you can still keep the content inside and hide it using opactiy or another technique (will edit the answer)