# Keep size of button stable when button text changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, resize

I have a `bootstrap` button:

```
<div class="float-right" >
    <label>show as </label>
    <input class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded active" type="button" value="percentage" onclick="toggle(this)" />
</div>
```

which I toggle the text using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(button) {
        if(button.value=="percentage") {
            button.value="units";
        } else {
            button.value="percentage";
        }
    }
</script>
```

How to I get the button **not to resize** when the text is changed from the longer word `percentage` to the shorter word `units`. i.e. I want the button to remain the same size as it is when it has the text `percentage`.

Note I would rather not hardcode the size using `style="min-width: 120px;"`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55328972/8620333 (if you are able to use `button` insitead of `input`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using `javascript`.

One of the options:

```html
<div class="float-right" >
    <label>show as </label>
    <input class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded active" type="button" value="percentage" onclick="toggle(this)" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(button) {
        const buttonWidth = button.offsetWidth;
        if(button.value=="percentage") {
            button.value="units";
            button.style.width = `${buttonWidth}px`;
        } else {
            button.value="percentage";
        }
    }
</script>
```